# Saving website copy and browsing saved copies

Tags: webserver, backups

How can I automatically save site's copy each week with an option to browse saved copies? I need kind of WebArchive, but on my local computer.

Comment: Is the site "copy" stored in a database or static HTML pages? From your comment below, you do appear to use a database (for something). You might need to implement some kind of versioning in the database itself?

Comment: It's dynamic (i.e. Wordpress) website. But I am looking for smart solution, which doesn't require lots and lots of programming, like if I was going to implement my own search engine with caching, etc...

Answer (score 3):

You could try using a program like HTTrack to perform a site mirror. This gives you a local browsable copy that you can archive.

Comment: Actually none of existing tools update all links correctly. Some sophisticated CSS-links are not updated, unfortunatelly. So, the only way I come to by the moment is to make locally unbrowsable copy and deploy it to server.

The huge advantage — it won't require database, thus allowing us to deploy copy automatically.

Comment: Ok, seeing that you said you're running a Wordpress site, I would still consider HTTrack, but combined with one of these plugins:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/static-html-output-plugin/
 ...or... 
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/really-static/
 ...which will generate a static version of your site which you will mirror with HTTrack. If you don't like these ideas, search the WordPress plugin repository for modules that related to archive, backup, mirror, etc...

Answer (score 2):

You can backup your website easily within the panel of your hosting account. After that, you can download the backup and, thanks to a server engine like Apache, you can browse it locally.

Comment: It's ok solution, but how do I browse many many copies without deploying each of them? As I said — like WebArchive?

Comment: @user1065145 You don't need to deploy. If, for example, you have all php or html pages, you simply have to unzip (or so) and browse

Comment: And database? Anyway it requires time and experience. I need a solution for dummy user.